# Replacing " Character by another character in a string

Tags: java

How do I replace Double quotes a well as single quotes for instance:
I want where there is a " to be replaced by nothing at all. I have tried

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replace('"','');
```

and it causes an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace ", escape the double quotes with \".
Use replaceAll() to provide a regex [\"\'] that recognizes all ' and " , and replace it with "" from a String to remove the values (replace them with nothing).

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replaceAll("[\"\']", "");

//To replace() without regex:-
String quoteid3 =quoteid2.replace("\"","").replace("\'","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to escape your quotes. Like so, might help:

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replace('\"','\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For replacing `"` , escape the the double quote `\"`, Similarly escape `'` with `\'`

Use `replaceAll()` to provide a regex `[\"\']` that recognizes all `'` and `"` , and replace it with `""` from a String to remove the values (replace them with nothing).

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replaceAll("[\"\']", "");
```

Or if you want to stick to using `replace()` without regex:-

```
String quoteid3 =quoteid2.replace("\"","").replace("\'","");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of `String.replace`, one that takes a pair of `char` values and the other that takes a pair of `String` values.  If you want the replacement value to be empty then you need to use the string version, i.e. use double (rather than single) quotes.

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replace("\"","");
```

In Java a single quoted literal is a `char` and so must be *exactly one* character - `''` is not valid.  Double quoted literals represent strings, so can be any number of characters from zero upwards.

Comment: `How do I replace Double quotes a well as single quotes ?`, yours will end up replacing only `"`, use `String quoteid3 =quoteid2.replace("\"","").replace("\'","");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An empty String is a wrapper on a `char[]` with no elements. You can have an empty `char[]`. But you cannot have an "empty" char. Like other primitives, a char has to have a value.

So if you want to replace all Double quotes a well as single quotes by nothing at all
you can try this :

```
String str1="Hossam Hassan \"Greeting you\" \'  \' \'";
System.out.println(str1);
String str2=str1.replaceAll("\"", "");
str2=str2.replaceAll("\'", "");
System.out.println(str2);
```

The result should be:

```
Hossam Hassan "Greeting you" '  ' '
Hossam Hassan Greeting you
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace " , escape the the double quote \", Similarly escape ' with \'

Use replaceAll() to provide a regex [\"\'] that recognizes all ' and " , and replace it with "" from a String to remove the values (replace them with nothing).

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replaceAll("[\"\']", "");
```

Or alternatively if you want to stick to using replace() without regex:-

```
String quoteid3 =quoteid2.replace("\"","").replace("\'","");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace " , escape the the double quote \", Similarly escape ' with \'

Use replaceAll() to provide a regex [\"\'] that recognizes all ' and " , and replace it with "" from a String to remove the values (replace them with nothing).

```
String quoteid3 = quoteid2.replaceAll("[\"\']", "");
```

Or alternatively if you want to stick to using replace() without regex:-

```
String quoteid3 =quoteid2.replace("\"","").replace("\'","");
```